# How to change a radio box from true to false using MVVM

Tags: mvvm

So I have a radio button that I want to change from being unchecked to being checked based on if a button is clicked. So 
the XAML code I have is:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="rdoExchange" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PauseRadioButton"  Command="{Binding PauseCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=check, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3"/>
```

And the View Model Code:

```
public string check = "True";

 public void Reset(object obj)
        {

            check = "True";
        }

  private ICommand m_PauseCommand;
    public ICommand PauseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return m_PauseCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            m_PauseCommand = value;
        }
    }

  private ICommand m_ResetCommand;
        public ICommand ResetCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ResetCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ResetCommand = value;
            }
        }

private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've left out the relaycommand code and several other parts that I feel would be irrelevant to solving the problem.

Comment: You are binding to a field and you don't seem to have shown the code which I assume calls `SetProperty<T>` to notify of the property change. Where is `PauseCommand`? What does it do?

Comment: I updated the code to display the pause command code.

Comment: Ok that still doesn't show anything useful - I assume the `ResetCommand` is targeting the `Reset` method. You need to notify the view that a property has changed using `INotifyPropertyChanged` - it looks like `SetProperty<T>` is doing that, but it's not clear if you are actually calling it anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

XAML:

```
    <RadioButton GroupName="rdoExchange" IsChecked="{Binding Path=OptionOneChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding ToggleOptionOne}" Height="20" />
```

View Model:

```
public class ViewModel: NotificationObject
{
     private bool _optionOneChecked;
    public bool OptionOneChecked
    {
        get { return _optionOneChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_optionOneChecked)) return;
            _optionOneChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("OptionOneChecked");
        }
    }

    public ICommand ToggleOptionOne
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(() => OptionOneChecked = !OptionOneChecked); }
    }
}
```

using the `NotificationObject` class from the PRISM NuGet package.